# How to prove the Comparison Test for series using only the definition

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-writing

I'm studying a book on proof techniques and it asks me to prove the Comparison Test for series using nothing more than the definition of covergence for series:

> Assume $0 \leq a_k \leq b_k$ for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Prove that,
>   if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n$ converges, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$
>   converges. Also prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ diverging implies
>   $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n$ diverges.

I am getting stuck in one part of the proof and would like a small **hint** to complete the exercise, but not the full solution. Also, nothing about boundedness or monoticity has been mentioned in the book, so I think I cannot use it.

First, I know one of this statements is the contrapositive of the other, so I only need to prove one. I will try to prove the first one. Since I don't see a way to use direct proof because I don't know the number $\sum a_n$ should converge to, I will attempt to use proof by contradiction.

**Proof attempt:** Assume $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n = S$ and suppose $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ diverges. So to set the notation up:

- Let $s_n = b_1 + b_2 + \dots + b_n$. So $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n = S$ means that $\lim_{n \to \infty} s_n = S$.
- Let $t_n = a_1 + a_2 + \dots + a_n$. So $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ diverging  means that $\lim_{n \to \infty} t_n \neq L$, for every $L \in \mathbb{R}$.

Whith this in mind, I noticed that $t_n \leq s_n$ for every $n$.

Applying the definition of convergence/divergence for series I get:

1. For every $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n > N$ implies $\lvert s_n - S \rvert < \epsilon$.
2. There is a $\epsilon > 0$ such that, for every $N \in \mathbb{N}$, there is a $n > N$ for which $\lvert t_n - L \rvert \geq \epsilon$, where $L \in \mathbb{R}$.

So taking $L = S$ in in (2) we get an $\epsilon_0 > 0$ such that for every $N \in \mathbb{N}$ we have a $n_0$ such that $n_0 > N$ and $\lvert t_{n_0} - S \rvert \geq \epsilon_0$. On the other hand, for $\epsilon_0$ definition (1) gives a $N_0 > 0$ such that $n > N_0$ implies $\lvert s_n - S \rvert < \epsilon_0$.

For $n_0 > N_0$ we have both $\lvert t_{n_0} - S \rvert \geq \epsilon_0$ and $\lvert s_{n_0} - S \rvert < \epsilon_0$. This is, $t_{n_0} - S \geq \epsilon_0$ or $t_{n_0} - S \leq -\epsilon_0$, and $-\epsilon_0 < s_{n_0} - S < \epsilon_0$.

If $t_{n_0} - S \geq \epsilon_0$ and $-\epsilon_0 < s_{n_0} - S < \epsilon_0$, we would have $s_{n_0} - S < \epsilon_0 \leq t_{n_0} - S \implies s_{n_0} < t_{n_0} $, which is impossible since $0 \leq t_n \leq s_n$, for every $n$.

However, for the assumption $t_{n_0} - S \leq -\epsilon_0$ and $-\epsilon_0 < s_{n_0} - S < \epsilon_0$ I cannot find any contradiction. I've tried moving things around, but nothing has panned out.

Another thing I could use is the "series convergence implies the sequence convergence to 0", which implies that ${b_n}$ converges to $0$ and, via the Squeeze Theorem, ${a_n}$ converges to $0$. But I don't see how this helps.

Also, if my approach is wrong o fruitless, any pointer in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your point 2 bullet looks unusual: Since you are assuming $t_n$ diverges to $\infty$, it means that for every (arbitrarily large) $L\in \mathbb{R}$ there is an $N$ such that $t_n>L$ for all $n>N$. You should not be using $\epsilon$ here in point 2. [And since you can choose any $L$ you want, why not choose $L=S+100$?]

Comment: @Michael The book actually shows examples of divergent series that do not diverge to infinity, and actually gives two definitions of divergence: the one I wrote in (2) and the one you write. It actually proves divergence to infinity implies divergence in my sense, but not the other way around. I wanted to use the most general definition.

Comment: Then, you should clarify the role of $L$ in your point 2, since I cannot understand your statement there.

Comment: @Michael I just negated the statement $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n \neq L$ for every $L \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: In point 2: You would need to clarify with a statement such as "for all $L \in \mathbb{R}$" or "for some $L \in \mathbb{R}$" and let us know if $L$ is chosen before $\epsilon$ and/or before $N$, or not.

Comment: @Michael I agree it is confusing. I'm gonna try prove this using the divergence definition you gave and then maybe rewrite the question to better clarify what I mean. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds good.  In general for this problem, I believe you will eventually need to prove that nondecreasing sequences $\{r_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ that are upper bounded must converge, that is, prove the fact that you are trying to avoid. A consequence is that nondecreasing sequences either diverge to $\infty$ or converge.

Comment: You'll need to use the completeness of the reals at some point and that will depend on how that has been formulated - either as an axiom or some theorem.  The result is not strictly true if you are dealing, say, with the rationals.  $1/2+1/4+1/8 \cdots $ converges to $1/2$ but $1/2 + 1/2\cdot 1/4 + 1/3 \cdot 1/8 +\cdots$ converges to (I hope) to the irrational number  $\log(2)$.  Given all terms are positive you can use completeness in the form that every bounded set has a supremum.